# Stuck on boot screen forever after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, boot-failure

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I was just upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10, and my computer restarted (I'm not sure if it finished or not). Then it got stuck on the Ubuntu loading screen. So, I restarted it and now it just doesn't stop loading. Does anyone know of any possible solution?

Comment: Nvidia graphics?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with this:

- Enter in safe-mode (dont remember the exact name, but for commandline)
- Type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and choose the lightdm.
- Reboot and done!

Comment: @JoeShaw if you are having trouble getting to Safemode due to Grub configuration, try [CTRL]+[ALT]+[F1] and attempt to  run the command Teo listed above after console logon. If you have nvidia graphics, there is quite an issue with display, and you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the upgrade Brick 4 of my computers.  One computer I was able to hit Tab key before the splash screen and boot to an older Kernel.  This got me to the Shell and I was able to startx and finish the install.  It appears that the system reboots before the upgrade process completes.   On one of my Newer computers which just had 11.04 installed, the TAB key trick didn't work.   So I held down the esc key to see where it was hanging (Battery) at that point you can CTRL-ALT F2 to another shell terminal and try and recover.

Oddly enough,  I have not had 11.10 upgrade work on any of my computers yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck at the login screen when I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10. I had to do a clean install from a cd and then had no problem.